# How to extract part of the text from input file and write into another file?

Tags: regex, perl, text, extract

Here is my code. I wish to extract part of the text and write into another file. The loop of the code do not stop at my selected range of text. It read until the final match line of word. Please advise me. Thanks. For example, I need to extract the $ NAME: sandy until $$.TO and then join with the contents inside $NAME: patrick which is start from G1 until $$SRU.

TEXT:

```
$ NAME : corry  
$$.Inc s d
$$.Oc s
$$.TO

G1 ty n1 EE EE M T1 T2 $$SRU
G2 n1 y OO OO M T3 T4 $$SRU    
$$.EON

$ NAME : patrick    
$$.Inc c d
$$.Oc c
$$.TO

G1 td n3 EE EE M T5 T6 $$SRU      
G2 n3 y OO OO M T7 T8 $$SRU    
$$.EON
$ NAME : sandy    
$$.Inc k l
$$.Oc l
$$.TO

G1 td n3 FF FF M R5 R6 $$SRU      
G2 n3 y OO OO N R7 R8 $$SRU    
$$.EON
```

CODE:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open my $F1, '<', 'testing.txt' or die "failed $!";
open my $F2, '>', 'out.txt' or die "failed $!";

while (<$F1>) {
if (/^\$ NAME : sandy/../\$.TO/) {
print $F2 $_;
}
if (/^\$ NAME : patrick/../\$.EON/) {
if(/^G1/../\$SRU){
 s/G1/G1.G1o.n/g;
print $F2 $_;}
}

 }
close $F1;
close $F2;
```

Comment: what piece of text do you need to extract?

Comment: Start from here->$ NAME : corry $$.Inc s d $$.Oc s $$.TO G1 ty n1 EE EE M T1 T2 $$SRU G2 n1 y OO OO M T3 T4 $$SRU $$.EON-<End here. Besides that,I would like to substitute G1 into G1.G1o.n before I write the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first of all there is not enought space before `:` in your regex, and you complicate your code...

```
use warnings;
use strict;

open my $fh, '<', 'in' || die "Can not open file:$!\n";;

while (<$fh>){
        print if /^\$ NAME : corry/../\$\$\.EON/;
}
close $fh;
```

If you need to write some data into other file first of all you need to open it for writing:

```
open my $fh2, '>>', 'my_out_file.txt'; #open file handler $fh2 associated with file named my_out_file.txt
```

then you can print to this file, like you print to the screen:

```
print $fh2 'some text here'; #print to file handler $fh2 string 'some text here'
```

Comment: Thanks! It works fine. Can you give me some idea on how I substitute G1 in the range of the selection text into G1.G1o.n and write the new text into another file?

Comment: Actually this text is some simple part from the whole text. G1.G1o.n refers to hierarchy organization. My perl skill is not standard yet so I'm thinking using rather old ways to substitute the G1 into G1.G1o.n

Comment: There are many small parts which make the final hierarchy section. the section corry and patrick are parts of the hierarchy. The overall hierarchy is under the section Manager which I din't post above.

Comment: May be because if my bad english or because of monday, but I dont realy understand what you want to do, sorry:D If you want to write line starting with G1 into another file you can do this `while (<$fh>){if (//..//){print $fh2 $_ if /^G1/;}}`

Comment: oh, is it mean `while (<$fh>){if /^\$ NAME : corry/../\$\$\.EON/;{print $fh2 $_ if /^G1/;}}`? Sorry, is it need to add something to create output file?

Comment: @user2865279 I updated my answer. also take a look at hwnd's answer. He writes to out file too

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. Is it `open my $fh2, '>>', 'my_out_file.txt'` after the `use warnings;
use strict;

open my $fh, '<', 'in' || die "Can not open file:$!\n";;

while (<$fh>){
        print if /^\$ NAME : corry/../\$\$\.EON/;
}
close $fh;
`?

Comment: I have try hwnd's answer but when i read the out file, there's nothing inside the file.

Comment: You need to open output file before you will write to it. So if you want to write output in `while` loop open it before loop. code from hwnd's answer works for me, please check file names or mistypes

Comment: Thanks. It works fine. From hwnd's answer, apparently is human error. Another question if you allow me, if there are many section that I would like to extract and write into the output file, is it following code?
use strict;
use warnings;

open my $F1, '<', 'file.txt' or die "failed $!";
open my $F2, '>', 'out.txt' or die "failed $!";

`while (<$F1>) {
   if (/^\$ NAME : corry/../\$\.EON/) {
     s/G1/G1.G1o.n/g;
     print $F2 $_;
   }
else if (/^\$ NAME : patrick/../\$\.EON/) {
     s/G1/G3.G3o.n/g;
     print $F2 $_;

}}
close $F1;
close $F2;`

Comment: this one will not work properly, remove `else` from your code, because if `patric` section will be before `corry` in the input file it will be ignored. so your code must looks like `if(// .. //){...} if (// .. //) {...}` and so on. But it's bad practice to repeat your code many times. DRY = Don't Repeat Yourself. But it's another long story not for comments on SO.

Comment: I see, thanks for the information. Because I have a lot data to refer on(substitution), I guess I have to repeat it many times.

Comment: if i do the second`if` loop  to sustitute another word, when i do `print $F2 $_;` will it over write the first 'if' loop data?

Comment: no, it will not, you can print to file everywhere and so much times as you want.

Comment: When I perform the second if loop, it doesnt stop print at the range of text that i want. It keep print and write till the final match word. I have update the code and text. Please advise me, thanks.

Comment: You had better create new question with your code. It's already too much comments here